# How should I check for any fork() in the infinite loop attack?

Tags: c, security

I compiled and executed this code and the computer hangs. I sent the file(a.out not a.c) to a friend and he executed it and the result was same. 
How do I intelligently check if there is such fork() in infinite loops? What should be the preventive measures against this attack?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    while(1)
        fork();    
}
```

Comment: Dump the machine code into assembly and look at it?

Comment: Don't execute code sent in emails titled "Hello friend"?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: How to dump the machine code into assembly ? Any recommended software or command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the **ulimit** to limit the maximum number of processes. Additionally you can configure the limitations by editting the **/etc/security/limits.conf** file. Take a look to the following link which provides more information about how to prevent from this attack:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-limiting-user-process.html